# How to get firebase device token

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

Can someone help me with this. I want to change "tokenas12345" on line 65 in main.dart to Firebase getToken. How can I do that? I have file notification.dart, where on line 47 we can see how we get device token. Thank you.
My main.dart file looks like this:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

import 'notification.dart';

void main() async {
  await init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future init() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String notificationTitle = 'No Title';
  String notificationBody = 'No Body';
  String notificationData = 'No Data';

  @override
  void initState() {
    final firebaseMessaging = FCM();
    firebaseMessaging.setNotifications();

    firebaseMessaging.streamCtlr.stream.listen(_changeData);
    firebaseMessaging.bodyCtlr.stream.listen(_changeBody);
    firebaseMessaging.titleCtlr.stream.listen(_changeTitle);

    super.initState();
  }

  _changeData(String msg) => setState(() => notificationData = msg);
  _changeBody(String msg) => setState(() => notificationBody = msg);
  _changeTitle(String msg) => setState(() => notificationTitle = msg);

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
        body: WebView(
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            Map<String, String> headers = {"x-device-id": "tokenas12345"};
            webViewController.loadUrl('https://www.google.com/', headers: headers);


          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

And my notification.dart file looks like this:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

Future<void> onBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  if (message.data.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final data = message.data['data'];
  }

  if (message.data.containsKey('notification')) {
    // Handle notification message
    final notification = message.data['notification'];
  }
  // Or do other work.
}

class FCM {
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final streamCtlr = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  final titleCtlr = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  final bodyCtlr = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  setNotifications() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(onBackgroundMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
          (message) async {
        if (message.data.containsKey('data')) {
          // Handle data message
          streamCtlr.sink.add(message.data['data']);
        }
        if (message.data.containsKey('notification')) {
          // Handle notification message
          streamCtlr.sink.add(message.data['notification']);
        }
        // Or do other work.
        titleCtlr.sink.add(message.notification!.title!);
        bodyCtlr.sink.add(message.notification!.body!);
      },
    );
    // With this token you can test it easily on your phone
    final token =
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((value) => print('Token: $value'));
  }

  dispose() {
    streamCtlr.close();
    bodyCtlr.close();
    titleCtlr.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In your main.dart, you can do
`String firebaseToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken()`
after
`await Firebase.initializeApp();`

Post that you can cache it or pass it to your widget.

Comment: lib/main.dart:17:32: Error: Undefined name 'FirebaseMessaging'.
  String firebaseToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();

Comment: import package `import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';`

Comment: but how it to use on line 65 where is "tokenas12345"?

Comment: you can save the value returned to a variable and then use it in your widget.